# Should I use the same object for independent, different database operations?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class DB:
  def insert(self, data):
      #connect to database and insert the data into Table.

  def update(self, data):
      #connect to database and update the Table.

class EditInfo:
  def Insert_into_Table(self, data):
      self.object1 = DB() #created the object here
      self.object1.insert()

  def update_the_Table(self, data):
      self.object1.update() #Reusing the same object created before
```

Referring to `object1`, is it a good idea to create just one object( like self.object1) for a class that does the Database operations frequently, and reusing it in several methods (like in Insert_into_Table(), update_the_Table() ) without bothering to delete it ?
Or, should I delete, calling `__del__`, the object created before and creating a new object every-time the need arises ?

Comment: It depends. And calling `__del__` probably doesn't do what you expect (and you would never call it explicitly anyway)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : Class A, is a dbms operations(like select, insert) class. And, the app is a Tkinter one, which would be communicating to a centralized DBMS, to be used by about 30 guys, on their own pc.

Comment: I'm not familiar Tkinter and stuff, but I'd say you need to add more details, impossible to tell without knowing exactly what your methods are supposed to do and what side effects (required or not) they may have...

Comment: @Julien: Did that, see the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reasonable to have a very low level object that is used to access the db and is reused over and over again.  In fact I think you're better off having a singleton that does the db access and is only created once per session.  The only question from there is if you should have layers between the DB object and your business logic (likely answer is yes).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please guide me as to where should I look for these kinds of details.